# Value extracted from the request is not being saved in the environment variable

Tags: javascript, postman, cheerio

I need to extract a token from an HTML response and set environment variable in postman.
I've tried to do so, but it does not give an error and does not save the value of the variable.

I need to extract the generated accessToken inside the second input:

```
<form id="appForm" method="post" name="oauthResponse"
        action="callback">
        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="EdPfpR"/>

        **<input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="accessToken"/>**

    </form>
```

I tried this way, but without success. It does not show an error and does not record the value of the id_token.

```
const id_token = cheerio.load(responseBody);
console.log(id_token("input[name='id_token']" ).val());
pm.environment.set("id_token", id_token.id_token);
```

**The code above extracts the token, but does not save it in the variable!**

[image: token]

[image: variable]

Comment: Does the log show the correct output or not? If so, then I'd skip the cheerio stuff since that's working and not part of the problem. If not, then I'd skip the postman stuff since it's clearly not part of the problem. Selector looks fine, so hopefully you've confirmed that the HTML is in fact what you think it is and your HTTP request is not being blocked. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Hello @ggorlen, it doesn't show anything in the log, neither correct output nor error message.
I can't share more code, for security reasons, so as not to expose the company's data, I'm sorry.

Comment: I understand, but there's not much to be done here if Cheerio can't find the element and you can't share the site, because the selector is fine for the HTML you posted. Are you sure this element exists in `view-source:` or the HTML response rather than injected dynamically via JS and visible in devtools? Request is not being blocked for sure?

Comment: @ggorlen Absolutely sure, everything is correct.

Comment: @ggorlen I think I discovered something, it's getting the token yes, it's just not setting it in the environment variable.
I can see the token in the console.

Comment: If it's logging, why are you using `pm.environment.set("id_token", id_token.id_token);` rather than `pm.environment.set("id_token", id_token("input[name='id_token']" ).val());`? You should `pm.environment.set()` the exact same thing you're passing to `console.log()`. `id_token.id_token` doesn't make sense, this is the cheerio equivalent of `$.id_token` which I'd expect to be undef.

Comment: @ggorlen 
It worked with pm.environment.set("id_token", id_token("input[name='id_token']" ).val());, if you want post this as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: Thanks and glad it worked out, but I don't think this has much value for future readers so I'll stick to my "not reproducible" close vote rather than answer. There was just a misunderstanding about how to call a function with the right data.